# Save value from a combobox and then clear the combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I have a form that with a lot of data validation. The form can be saved.

In the last update I added an ActiveX Combobox. People can choose from different license plates and it auto-fills so fewer errors are made.

I want the value filled in the combobox to be saved and the combobox field to be empty when the 'save button' is pressed.

This is the code I currently have:

```vb
Sub Store_Data()
    'Takes data from one worksheet and stores it in the next empty row
    
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim nextRow As Integer
    Dim xCombox As OLEObject --- Not sure this is correct
    
    Set sourceSheet = Sheets("Départ")
    Set dataSheet = Sheets("Data Départ")
    Set xCombox = sourceSheet.OLEObjects("TempCombo") '--- not sure this is correct
     
    'A is the colums is that will always be there; here it is matricule - unique data
    nextRow = dataSheet.Range("A" & dataSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 1).Value = sourceSheet.Range("F4").Value
    dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 2).Value = sourceSheet.Range("F6").Value
    dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 3).Value = sourceSheet.Range("F8").Value

    ' ---- I used LinkedCell and then use the value of this cell to add to my database,
    ' because I have no idea how to retrieve data from the combobox directly.
    dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 4).Value = sourceSheet.Range("L10").Value

    dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 5).Value = sourceSheet.Range("F12").Value
    dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 6).Value = sourceSheet.Range("F14").Value
    dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 7).Value = sourceSheet.Range("F16").Value
    dataSheet.Cells(nextRow, 8).Value = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")
    
    'Clear Data
    sourceSheet.Range("F4").Value = ""
    sourceSheet.Range("F8").Value = ""
    sourceSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TempCombo")).Clear '----- This one gives an error
    sourceSheet.Range("F12").Value = ""
    sourceSheet.Range("F14").Value = ""
    sourceSheet.Range("F16").Value = ""
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
End Sub
```

Most of these codes I retrieved from the internet.

This is how the combobox looks and is named. (My Excel is in Dutch).
[image]